# How to add custom phtml in catalog view page in magento2

Tags: magento2, catalog, frontend

I want to add some custom code in my catalog category view page. I don't want to override product/list.phml file . But just display my custom code in catagory view page.

How to add it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create catalog_category_view.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_Module::myCustomFile.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Now create myCustomFile.phtml and place your code**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/myCustomFile.phtml

```
<?php

echo "This is my custom file for product list page";

?>
```

Comment: want to add in app/code

Comment: @RohanHapani. See my updated answer :)

Comment: Your always Welcome :) Happy Coding...!

Comment: @RohanHapani, Accept answer for help other developers to find their solutions

Comment: @PrincePatel, I need to add the same in custom module, what changes are required load the template in category list page?

Comment: @PrincePatel, I need to add in detail page, so i added the above code in catalog_product_view.xml, but I need to load that template based on some attribute value, how that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block after="product.info.price" class="Vendor/Module/Block/Module" name="extra" template="Vendor_Module::extra.phtml" />        
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: please accept my answer

Comment: Hi @Jjo the above file calling at the end of list section not after the price

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in `calatog_category_view.xml` and replace the block name and template name with your custom block and template name

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">

                        <block as="product_list_blockname"  
                            class="<vendor>\<module>\Block\Product\<ClassName>"
                            name="product.list.<ClassName>" 
                            template="<template path>"/>

                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```