# Magento 2.2.6 : Add custom phtml file after product price in category page

Tags: magento2, category, frontend

I want to add custom code in my catalog category view page. **I don't want to override product/list.phml file** .

But, Just display my custom code in catagory view page after product price.

How to add it?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that without overriding the list.phtml file

Comment: You can see here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181717/how-to-add-custom-phtml-in-catalog-view-page-in-magento2 But it's not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom phtml in catalog view page in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181717/how-to-add-custom-phtml-in-catalog-view-page-in-magento2)

Comment: @ManashviBirla see my above comment what I said. It's not working for me.

Comment: What is the work of that phtml?

Comment: @SukumarGorai. For display my custom text. I want to display count down timer.

Comment: @Sukumar is there any other way as per magento standard way?

Comment: You need to copy the list.phtml from vendor to your theme and call it there is a good practice.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml in this file I added <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item> here my phtml file. Then, I get perfect output. But, want to add in my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find one way. Maybe It'll helpful for you.

Create **di.xml** file at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` :

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="block-product-list" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\ProductList"/>
</type>
```

Create Plugin file **ProductList.php** at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin` :

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

class ProductList
{   

    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        echo "call";
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in `calatog_category_view.xml` and replace the block name and template name with your custom block and template name

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">

                        <block as="product_list_blockname"  
                            class="<vendor>\<module>\Block\Product\<ClassName>"
                            name="product.list.<ClassName>" 
                            template="<template path>"/>

                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```