# how to create a page with xml and phtml? I am using Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, custompage

I am trying to create a custom page with xml and phtml and I do not know the right way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different files in Magento 2.

There are configuration files with extension *.xml* and template files with extension *.phtml*

You can see some of configuration files at Vendor/Module/etc/ and template files at  Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template

Here is an example how to create an xml file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614680/10193644

Example for template file

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/181719/67038

Good Luck